# Groovy - How to get map value with default without updating the map

Tags: dictionary, groovy

How to read value for the given key from a map, with providing a default value (used if the map doesn't contain entry for the specified key),
but without updating the map - this is what `get` method does:

> `get(Object key, Object defaultValue)`
>
> Looks up an item in a Map for the given key and returns the value - unless there is no entry for the
>   given key ***in which case add the default value to the map*** and return
>   that.

1. Ofc it must be a single, short expression
2. For performance reasons, creating a deepcopy on that map (so it could be updated) and using mentioned `get` is not a solution.

Equivalents in different languages:

- *JavaScript*: `map["someKey"] || "defaultValue"`
- *Scala*: `map.getOrElse("someKey", "defaultValue")`
- *Python3*: `map.get("someKey", "defaultValue")`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given the examples you gave for some other languages and your expressed requirement to not update the Map, maybe you are looking for something like this...

```
map.someKey ?: 'default value'
```

Note that with that, if someKey does exist but the value in the Map associated with that key is null, or zero, false, or anything that evaluates to false per Groovy truth rules, then the default value will be returned, which may or may not be what you want.

An approach that is more verbose might be something like this...

```
map.containsKey('someKey') ? map.someKey : 'default value'
```

Comment: Correct but a bit long. Possible to write anything shorter?

Comment: The requirements are not very detailed but if the requirement is something like, if the Map contains a certain key, return that value, otherwise return some default value that I have provided AND the Map should not be mutated as part of the process (which is what is expressed in the original question), then I don't know of a shorter syntax to express that.  You could meta program your own method onto Map which does the work and that could simplify the call.

Answer (score 26):

Use Java's getOrDefault Map method (since Java 8):

```
map.getOrDefault("someKey", "defaultValue")
```

it will not add new key to the map.